# How does unordered insertion behave in db.collections.insert() in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.products.insert(
   [
     { _id: 20, item: "lamp", qty: 50, type: "desk" },
     { _id: 21, item: "lamp", qty: twenty, type: "floor" },
     { _id: 22, item: "bulk", qty: 100 }
   ],
   { ordered: false }
)
```

I am trying to insert three documents in the collection `products`, but the second document has an error, the `qty` field has erroneous value. I am using `ordered: false` so I am expecting that all the other documents should get inserted except the second one, but this is not the case, none of the documents get inserted.

Then what is the difference between ordered and unordered insertion? How can I achieve the desired results in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered/unordered inserts are distinguished on the server side.

If you don't have the `twenty` variable defined, the error happens on the client side and no insert is attempted at all.

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: Inserting multiple documents with the same _id is the easiest way to attain that failure.